# Matching text either side of a colon

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to learn the basics of regular expressions (in Java) and imagined some sample scenarios to practice, and – as you might have expected – the last (and thus for me hardest) isn't working. Here it is:

```
<[a-zA-Z]>:[a-zA-Z]
```

What I want it to do is to recognize `<SOME TEXT>:SOME MORE TEXT`. With input like: `<foo>:bar`, it isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only matching one character. To match multiple, you need to add '+':

```
<[a-zA-Z]+>:[a-zA-Z]+
```

If the text is optional, you can also specify '*', which means "zero or more". '+' means "1 or more"

Comment: And don't forget spaces if they can be in the text

Comment: I don't need spaces (yet). But thanks for noticing! @IgorChubin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to also catch "SOME TEXT" literally, you need to catch white space too.

```
    String teststring = "<SOME TEXT>:SOME MORE TEXT";
    String regex = "<[\\sa-zA-Z]+>:[\\sa-zA-Z]+";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(teststring);
    while (m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(teststring.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    }
```

Comment: No, I don't need whitespace in there. Thanks nonetheless! +1.

Comment: If you want to simplify the code, you can replace the print statement with `System.out.println(m.group());`.